# how to load both csv and excel file in sql server using single connection manager in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I want to load two types of file (CSV and Excel) which are placed in one folder in a signal sql server table. The no of column and column names are same in both files. How can we achieve this through SSIS using single Connection Manager?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't simply use 2 Connections and merge their data?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing something very over engineered in a script source task, this is not possible.  Just have two connection managers, two data sources in the Data Flow and merge the two datasets with a `Union All` transformation.